# Build does not contain the correct beta entitlement [Again After generate distribution certificate]

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6

After upload Build i'm facing issue "Build 1.2.0 does not contain the correct beta entitlement"
i create latest distribution certificate but show again this issue one more can apple reject this app for this reason or not.

Answer (score 0):

Beta test is optional, you will have to switch it off in itunesconnect. Please review the documentation and refer to the below link (will work with valid developer account)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2